# Генерация строки из массива

Tags: php, массивы, преобразование, строки

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как из ассоциативного массива сгенерировать вот такую строку:

```
`Ключ` = 'Значение',
```

Я делаю это с помощью `foreach`:

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
  $text .= "`$key` = '$val', ";
}
```

Но возможно есть более правильный метод это делать?
@Etki предлагал делать это с помощью [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php) ,но через эту функцию не получается сделать, так как она не работает с ассоциативными массивами, как хотелось бы.

Вот пример, есть массив:

```
array(
  'test1' => 'data1',
  'test2' => 'data2'
)
```

Из этого массива должна получится строка:

```
`test1` = 'data1', `test2` = 'data2'
```

Comment: Какую результирующую строку и для чего (для бд же, верно?) вам надо получить?

Comment: @Etki , добавил пример, да, для БД.

Comment: Если вы где-то не фильтруете данные - то ваш код будет подвержен sql-инъекциям, поэтому не надо изобретать велосипед, а начните работать с апи баз данных для php - `mysqli` или `PDO`.

Comment: На самом деле все это можно [сделать одной строкой без цикла.](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.print-r.php) Правда форматирование будет несколько отличаться от желаемого: `$my_string=print_r($my_array,true);`

Answer (score 1):

- Во-первых, sprintf для этого вполне подходит.
- Во-вторых, эта функция здесь лишняя.
- В-третьих, перед тем как генерировать строку, надо сначала отфильтровать массив.
- В-четвертых, у строки неправильный формат.
- В-пятых, такую строку в принципе генерировать нельзя.

Далi буде...

**Пункт первый.** Многие не понимают предназначения функции `sprintf()`. Эта функция нужна для того, чтобы один шаблон строки можно было хранить и редактировать отдельно от кода.

Например, вот мы подготовили шаблон вида

```
$text = "Здравствуйте %s! Я Вам должен  %d миллионов. Так вот, я их не отдам!";
```

И после этого можно рассылать письма кредиторам в том же самом цикле:

```
foreach($arr as $key = >$val)
{
  $text .= sprintf($text, $key, $val);
}
```

**Пункт второй.** Однако по какой-то неизвестной мне причине, эту функцию часто используют вместо строки в двойных кавычках. Что не дает никакого положительного эффекта, а вот читабельность снижает очень сильно. Сравним:

```
$text .= "`$key` = '$val', ";
$text .= sprintf("`%s` = '%s', ", $key, $val);
```

во втором случае код раздувается в два раза за счет абсолютно ненужных символов, при этом теряя а читабельности: если в первом варианте мы сразу видим какая переменная идет в какое место строки, то во втором приходится мысленно сопоставлять переменную с плейсхолдером.

**Пункт третий.**
Если массив берется из пользовательского ввода, то его надо сначала отфильтровать, оставив в нем только те элементы, ключи которых были заранее прописаны в коде. (Если массив формируется в скрипте, то этот пункт выполнять не надо).

**Пункт четвертый.**
Формат строки никуда не годится. Ни имя поля, ни значение не отформатированы. Это сразу двойка с минусом и SQL инъекция.

**Пункт пятый.**
В 2015 году пора бы уже научиться подставлять в запрос данные через плейсхолдеры. С одной стороны, у нас конечно имена полей все равно идут в запрос динамически, но тут уж ничего не поделаешь. Но вот значения, при некотором усилии, мы можем передать через плейсхолдеры. чем и следовало бы воспользоваться:

```
$set   = '';
$comma = '';
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    $set  .= "$comma `".str_replace("`","``",$key)."` = ?";
    $comma = ",";
}
```

таким образом мы получим строку, в которой имена полей отформатированы на предмет предотвращения инъекций, а для значения пишется плейсхолдер. Который будет заменен на актуальные данные при исполнении запроса.

**Бонус:**
[Готовая библиотека](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql), моего авторства, которая выполняет нужный запрос единственно правильным способом:

```
$data = array(
  'test1' => 'data1',
  'test2' => 'data2'
)
$db->query("INSERT INTO table SET ?u", $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться [YaLinqo](https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo) (©я). Положим:

```
$a = [ 'a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd' ];
```

Тогда можно получить нужную строку так:

```
from($a)->toString(', ', function ($v, $k) { return "`$k` = '$v'"; });
```

Или ещё короче:

```
from($a)->toString(', ', '"`$k` = \'$v\'"');
```

P.S. Для тех, кто строит запросы SQL таким образом, в аду отдельный котёл.

Comment: Слишком уж открытый самопиар, не кажется?

Comment: @TheDoctor У Полковника Шрапнеля тоже самопиар. =) А вообще да, правильно, добавил упоминание сего факта в соответствии с правилами.

Comment: Понятия не имею кто этот полковник.
Как самая короткая версия работает? Ясно что раппер `join`, но в целом не очень ясно.

Comment: @TheDoctor Вторая версия преобразуется в первую (первая — implode + array_map). Это короткая запись анонимных функций, поддерживаемая YaLinqo. Полковник Шрапнель = Colonel Shrapnel = Your Common Sense = Shorty = Ипатьев. Он является автором библиотеки SafeMySQL, которая позволяет экранировать куски запросов самыми дикими способами. Пора бы уже знать героев.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле без разницы, как это делать, подход практически один и тот же, а пройтись и по ключам, и по значениям c помощью коллбэка позволит только `array_walk()`, и не самым лучшим образом. Я действительно поклонник sprintf, поэтому у меня бы это выглядело так:

```
$chunks = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $chunks[] = sprintf('`%s` = \'%s\'', $key, $value);
}
return implode(', ', $chunks);
```

Однако, вероятнее всего, это решается совсем иным путем через решение самой задачи с БД. Любые попытки устроить произвольные поисковые условия так или иначе перерастают в query builder, который такой массив поедает одним аргументом. Если это часть `UPDATE` - тем более не рекомендую делать такие вещи руками, есть куча готовых библиотек для работы с БД.

Comment: На счёт готовых библиотек, мне кажутся они не удобными, по этому я и решил попробовать сам написать.

Comment: Я бы не назвал ручное формирование запроса удобным и безопасным. Доктрина же берет на себя вообще всю головную боль, которую можно представить, пусть и похожа на Hibernate один-в-один.